# Localstack - AWS SAM docker container is not able to connect to Localstack docker container

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-sam, localstack

Starting the localstack by running

`$Env:EDGE_BIND_HOST="0.0.0.0"; localstack start -d`

a docker container will be created and available at http://0.0.0.0:4566 mocking AWS services

Lambda Purpose is to return the weather report given city name,

- First search in s3 bucket with city_name if found return that data
- else call Openweatherapi by city_name and insert into s3 bucker and return the data

To run my lambda function with API gateway locally, by

`samlocal local start-api`

a new docker container will be created and available at http://172.0.0.1:3000 with API gateway endpoints

When trying to connect to localstack resources from sam-container,

```
response = requests.get(url="http://0.0.0.0:4566/health")
```

or

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3', endpoint_url="http://0.0.0.0:4566/")
print(s3.list_buckets())
```

Sam server is throwing below error

```
{'errorMessage': "HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=4566)
```

I have tried using --docker-network aswell, creating a docker network and add two containers to same network. Still the issue persists.

Is there anything needed to added or another approach to follow?

Comment: "0.0.0.0" is a special address that means basically "all". When you tell a program to bind to 0.0.0.0, you're telling it bind to all interfaces on the system with an IP addresss. 0.0.0.0 is not a real address that can be routed to.